# not getting location on Google map by name

Tags: android, geocoding

I am trying to getting location or want to show location on map by passing location name.
I did one sample project which show current location on map. But i don't understand how to pass name and search place on Google map.
Here is my code which may help you to understand my problem.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
    mapController = mapView.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(14); // Zoom 1 is world view
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0,
        0, new GeoUpdateHandler());

    myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(this, mapView);
    mapView.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);

    String value = "kasarwadi,pune";
    // Do something with value!


    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
      try {
          List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
              value, 5);
          String add = "";
          if (addresses.size() > 0) {
           GeoPoint   p = new GeoPoint(
                      (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                      (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
              mapController.animateTo(p);    
              mapView.invalidate();
          }    
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }

    myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        mapView.getController().animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
      }
    });

    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.point);
    itemizedoverlay = new MyOverlays(this, drawable);
    createMarker();
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
  }

  public class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         String value = "kasarwadi,pune";
         // Do something with value!


         Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());    
           try {
               List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(
                   value, 5);
               String add = "";
               if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                GeoPoint   p = new GeoPoint(
                           (int) (addresses.get(0).getLatitude() * 1E6), 
                           (int) (addresses.get(0).getLongitude() * 1E6));
                   mapController.animateTo(p);    
                   mapView.invalidate();
               }    
           } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
  }

  private void createMarker() {
    GeoPoint p = mapView.getMapCenter();
    OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(p, "", "");
    itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    if (itemizedoverlay.size() > 0) {
      mapView.getOverlays().add(itemizedoverlay);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.enableCompass();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    myLocationOverlay.disableCompass();
  }
```

I also generate MD5 fingerprint and valid api key. but when i am trying to show it show only current location but i need to show location which name pass by me.
Please give me an reference or hint.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is it pointing to? somewhere around pune or completely different location?

Comment: somewhere around pune...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem on my emulator as well, may be it will end up working on device (not tested it on device yet!)so how i got around this is by using another raw api to translate address to geopoint ...

so, i would suggest don't remove or change your current code (coz it looks fine to me and who knows may end up working on the device scenario), however call this method tryAlternative() in your catch (IOException) clause. I am writing down tryAlternative()

```
private void tryAltesrnative(String address) {

    String strCompleteAddress = address.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
    String streetName = strCompleteAddress.substring(strCompleteAddress.indexOf(",")+1);
    String cityName = streetName.substring(streetName.indexOf(",")+1);
    String addressToToast = "";


    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://maps.google." + "com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=" + address + "ka&sensor=false");


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    Double lon = new Double(0);
    Double lat = new Double(0);

    try {

        lon = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lng");

        lat = ((JSONArray)jsonObject.get("results")).getJSONObject(0)
            .getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location")
            .getDouble("lat");

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }








     point = new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lon * 1E6));

     mapController.animateTo(point);
     mapController.setZoom(12);

     List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
     Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_green);
     AddItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new AddItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

     OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "Customer", addressToToast);

     itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
     mapView.invalidate();

     Toast.makeText(this, "Lat: " + point.getLatitudeE6() +", Lon:  "+ point.getLongitudeE6() + "Address: " + addressToToast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are asking for a max of 5 addresses

```
List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(value, 5);
```

There is a chance that the 5th or last location latitude and longitude are completely different from the 1st values (which are more appropriate).

and you are trying to animate to the last location. Try animating to the 1st location.